# Renewal of Nevada drivers license while living in China

Tags: usa, driving-license

I want to return to America for a visit every other year, as I am now living in China. I need to be able to drive while in the US. I cannot get a Chinese drivers license, because I am too old. I'm 74, and China limits drivers licenses to those under 69.

My Nevada drivers license expires before I will travel back to US. Can I renew it when there? I do not have a Nevada residential address.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/how-do-i-renew-a-usa-drivers-license-if-i-am-as-us-citizen-living-abroad-with-no?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You may be out of luck.

While Nevada DMV provides for [out of state renewal by mail or via internet](http://www.dmvnv.com/dlrenewal.htm) but suggests contacting them prior to submitting the form there are some requirements that you're unlikely to meet:

1. You need a Nevada Address
2. You will need to attach your eye exam if renewing out of state by mail
3. Since you're over 71 you will need a medical report from a licensed physician.

Plus if you have not renewed your license in 8 years you must renew in person.