# Changing States to renew driving licence while living abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, california

I currently have a New York drivers license and have been living in the UK for 3 years and have to renew it. Unfortunately my permanent address is currently in California, so I am unable to renew the New York one. How am I able to get a California drivers license without going back to the US?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably can't.  Since you don't actually live in California, you may even be ineligible for a California license. Even if you are eligible, they'll have to take your picture, for which you must be physically present.

Comment: Also note that your driving licence is invalid in the UK after 12 months of being there (so if you've been driving with it it was already invalid for the past 2 years). If you want to continue driving in the UK you have to pass the test there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to renew a US driver's license when living abroad](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-to-renew-a-us-drivers-license-when-living-abroad)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You'll need to physically show up at the DMV with your New York license to exchange it for the California one.